# Is there any school of thought or ideology that explicitly advocate suicide?

Tags: death, life

I was curious if there's any ideology that does not criticize suicide or even advocate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a survey about different views on suicide in the history of philosophy see the Stanford Online encyclopedy on [suicide](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/suicide/#AncClaVieSui):

> In contrast, the Stoics held that whenever the means to living a
> naturally flourishing life are not available to us, suicide may be
> justified, regardless of the character or virtue of the individual in
> question.

Presently exist in Europe several associations which support people who want to end their life, e.g., in Germany [DGHS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Gesellschaft_f%C3%BCr_Humanes_Sterben). Similar units exist in other European countries.

Comment: I think that "the means to living a naturally flourishing life" are out of reach of many people, and often have been throughout time. I suppose it would depend on where one is in their lifespan and how the conditions came to be that way.

Answer (score 3):

There is [**Seppuku**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku).

The Samurai practised this as a way of ending their life, to avoid capture, or as a result of cultural shame. In the latter case, the act became ritualised, often perfomed in public.

Seppuku was also practised in World War II by Japanaese officers to restore honour for themselves or for their families.

Ending their life by their own hand was considered to be an honourable way to die.